# Sitemap Graphql query returns blank data

Tags: graphql, sxa-jss

I am trying to fetch Sitemap in my `NextJs` app using `GraphQLSitemapXmlService` plugin. This is XM Cloud and I am using Preview API locally.
During investigation, I realized that it is fetching response from following query which returns blank data (even in playground board). I have confirmed that other services are returning data like `GraphQLRobotsService`. What could be the problem?

(FYI, CM site also returns data with sitemap url)

```
query SitemapQuery($siteName: String!) {
   site {
     siteInfo(site: $siteName) {
       sitemap
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Are you fetching from the preview end point or the published end point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Experience Edge, you will need to store Sitemap in Media Item (This is recommended for XM Cloud version).

[image]

https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/configure-a-sitemap.html

And make sure that you have media folder selected in Site Item's `Sitemap media items` field -

[image]

Hope this helps !!